# How can I pass additional input arguments to odeint function in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, ode

I have a system of ordinary differential equations with external deterministic inputs (controls) and stochastic components. How can I safely (performing good code style) pass these additional input arguments to equation function through `tf.contrib.integrate.odeint()` besides initial state? If there is such a way to do it. Or defining them in the outer scope and referring to them from within the equation function is the only way to do it so far?

Comment: Could you construct a very simplified example problem and add to the question how you tried to solve it? Something like `x'=Ax+Bu+Cz` with `u` the control and `z` some noise.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when I try to simulate an Hindmarsh-Rose model by using odeint solver. I would like to inject a current in the equation and do not know how to do it.
Here after a basic example :

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

## Model parameters
# v' = u - a.v^3 + b.v^2 + I -z
# u' = c - d.v^2 -u
# z' = epsilon_z.(s.(v-v0)-z

#parameters for v and u terms
a = 1.0
b = 3.0
c = -3.0
d = 5.0
v0 = -1.4
s = 4.0
epsilon_z = 0.002

# init tensions
v_init = -3.0
u_init = 0.0
z_init = +0.9

#injected current that is currently fixed
Id = 5

# What I would like to do :
# def I(t):
#    if 0.0 <= t < 300.0:
#        return 0.0
#    elif 300.0 <= t < 1700.0:
#        return Iech
#    return 0.0

def HR_equation(state, t):
    v, u, z = tf.unstack(state)    
    dv = -a * v*v*v + b * v*v + u - z + I
    du = -d * v*v - u + c
    dz = epsilon_z * ( s*(v - v0)- z
    return tf.stack([dv, du, dz])

init_state = tf.constant([v_init, u_init, z_init], dtype=tf.float64)

t = np.linspace(0, 2000, num=5000)
tensor_state, tensor_info = tf.contrib.integrate.odeint(HR_equation,         
init_state, t, full_output=True)

sess = tf.Session()
state, info = sess.run([tensor_state, tensor_info])
v, u, z = state.T
plt.plot(v, u)
```